# List of all dates in a document

Tags: macros, table-of-contents

I have a command `\date{}{}` that simply takes a date and an event and prints "date -- event"

What I wanna do is create another command that lists all the events I created throughout the document.

Can anyone recommend a way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Something like `Table of contents`?  `\date` is a command used by many classes, it should not be redefined unless knowning what it does

Comment: Exactly like table of contents, but I dont wanna list the sections, but the events (I havent actually named it "date")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Here is a quick way with `\addcontentsline` that adds the dates to a `.dates` file and displays it with `\listofdates`, which is a hijacking - macro, i.e. it changes `\tableofcontents` within a TeX group, such that it is safe outside, i.e. the original `\@starttoc` and `\tableofcontents` still work as usual and be used without problems in any document.

I used `\dateevent` as macro name however, in order to keep the original `\date` and introduced a formatting helper macro, named `\dateformatter`, which can be redefined at will, here it is just typing the date in bold letters and the event title in italics.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\dateformatter}[2]{%
  \textbf{#1} -- \textit{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\dateevent}[2]{%
  \addcontentsline{dates}{section}{#1 -- #2}%
  \dateformatter{#1}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\listofdates}{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{List of Dates}
  \let\old@starttoc\@starttoc
  \def\@starttoc##1{%
    \old@starttoc{dates}%
  }
  \tableofcontents%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofdates


\blindtext

\dateevent{2019/01/01}{Upvote answers}

\blindtext

\dateevent{2019/01/02}{Accept answers}

\blindtext[2]

\dateevent{2019/01/03}{Upvote more answers}



\end{document}
```